Ubuntu randomly deleted my WiFi driver?
So, a weird thing happened with my WiFi - I originally posted about losing it, but I now have it back, but with other weird stuff happening.
My WiFi comes from a USB dongle that I've been using for literally years. Suddenly, 3 days ago, no WiFi. Still works when I boot into Windows, so that wasn't the problem. Turns out, for some reason, Ubuntu seems to have uninstalled the driver. I installed them via the terminal again, and I had WiFi again. But the weirdness didn't stop.
It still had my home WiFi listed under known networks. And yet, I had to completely reconnect as though for the first time. And sure enough, it has now called this "new" connection my network's name with a "1" at the end of it. Any clue what's going on with Ubuntu and the WiFi settings in my system?
EDIT - Running LTS 22.04.4

So the problem is fixed? If so it might be a bit too late to diagnose the problem I guess, but I guess what happened is that your kernel updated and that your previous driver wasn't compatible with the new kernel, hence just reinstalling (a presumably newer version) fixed it. I wouldn't lose sleep over this though.

No, I used the same driver as before, and it's still not recognizing its previously known networks.

If you believe that @kos conjecture is wrong (warning: It's often correct), then review your logs for clues. Your logs are timestamped, and you seem to know approximately when the mysterious event(s) occurred, so your review should not take long. Without details, you are asking us to speculate, which is a terrible idea.

I was simply saying the problem wasn't fixed. His conjecture about it being a kernel issue might very well be the case, but I pulled the same driver out from the cd that came with the dongle before, so I do know it was the same one, and it's still not recognizing known networks, though i can create "new" connections to old networks.
Not asking anyone to speculate, was just seeing if anyone else had run into a similar issue and therefore might know how to resolve it.

I'll leap even forward then and say that by all odds your driver installation script involves compiling the driver from source against the kernel (as this is the way manufacturers usaully ship drivers for Linux, considering that kernel updates may, in fact, break compatibility with older drivers), and even the same version might have ended up working on the new kernel after "reinstalling" (in this case "recompiling" rather). That is not to say that my conjecture is correct (at all!), all I want to say is that your issue is still explainable with "kernel updated".

Failing that as @user535733 mentions all you're left with is going through logs, or waiting for someone, perhaps blindly, stating that "it was because of x that happened due to y"; frustratingly enough many same issues can stem from different problems, and ultimately the real truth can probably only be found in the logs I believe :)
